# How to change this in random list by default without selection?

Tags: php, html, list

Random list without selection

```
<div class="properties-filter-sort-by-wrapper">
   <select class="form-control" name="filter-sort-by">
      <option value=""><?php
echo __('Sort by', 'realia'); ?></option>
      <option value="price" <?php

if (!empty($_GET['filter-sort-by']) && 'price' == $_GET['filter-sort-by']): ?>selected="selected"<?php
endif; ?>><?php
echo __('Price', 'realia'); ?></option>
      <option value="title" <?php

if (!empty($_GET['filter-sort-by']) && 'title' == $_GET['filter-sort-by']): ?>selected="selected"<?php
endif; ?>><?php
echo __('Title', 'realia'); ?></option>
      <option value="published" <?php

if (!empty($_GET['filter-sort-by']) && 'published' == $_GET['filter-sort-by']): ?>selected="selected"<?php
endif; ?>><?php
echo __('Published', 'realia'); ?></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to happen? Are you just asking how to mark one entry as default? Or is there more to it?

Comment: I want the list to appear randomly each refresh  without selection title or price or appears (The selection must disappear)
thanks :)

Comment: Well if you refresh the page that the form is on normally there shouldn't be anything selected...? It looks like you tried to select the one that was last selected though. Did you write that code? What did you try to accomplish? If you want nothing select why didn't you just output the different options without the php to check which is selected?

Comment: I tried the code but it always gives me the selection of the last time even though I refreshed the page so I don't know how to make it random
Either by ID or I change the code (shuffle)

Comment: It's because you are asking what the current $_GET['filter-sort-by'] value was and you're setting that item active. Why did you include that code if it doesn't do what you want? I don't think I understand what your problem is. Did you write that code yourself or did you just find it somewhere?

Comment: In fact the code was on a template in which when I choose all the properties the display is done by selection while I don't want the selection by selection I want the display has random and the selection must disappear, I hope that I give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if I understood you right, what you want to achieve is to not have any pre-selected options.

I think you'll just have to remove the calls checking which option is currently selected. So your code would look like this:

```
<div class="properties-filter-sort-by-wrapper">
    <select class="form-control" name="filter-sort-by">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="price">
            <?php echo __('Price', 'realia'); ?>
        </option>
        <option value="title">
            <?php echo __('Title', 'realia'); ?>
        </option>
        <option value="published">
            <?php echo __('Published', 'realia'); ?>
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Why?

I removed all these code parts:

```
<?php if (!empty($_GET['filter-sort-by']) && 'xxx' == $_GET['filter-sort-by']): ?>selected="selected"<?php
endif; ?>
```

because those check the value for this option is currently checked - and if that option is currently checked it will mark the option als selected by adding the attribute "selected" to it.

To the second part of your question: you want the items in the options list to be random?

I guess the simplest way to do that would be to stick the options into an array, shuffle that, and then output them again.

I would clearly advise against shuffling the items in your filter list though, that's bad usability.

Comment: thnaks 
I try the code and I will response you tomorow
But I have a question the display will be random after each refresh?

Comment: What do you want to be random? The order of the element in the list? Or the sorting of the elements that the sorting option is for? Your elements will be in "default" ordering. I have no idea what order that is because you provided no code as to where the elements are coming from.

Comment: OK I see is that there is a possibility of creeing a specific code for the 'title' and 'price'  'publication' is random?

Comment: hi this is tha All code

<div class="properties-sort">
 <form method="get" action="?" id="sort-form">
  <?php $skip = array(
   'filter-sort-by',
  'filter-sort-order',
  ); ?>

  <?php foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) : ?>
   <?php if ( ! in_array( $key, $skip ) ) : ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_html( $value ); ?>">
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: div class="properties-sort-inner">
   <div class="properties-filter-sort-title">
    <h3><?php echo __( 'Sorting options', 'realia' ); ?></h3>
   </div><!-- /.filter-sort-title -->

Comment: iv class="properties-filter-sort-by-wrapper">
    <select class="form-control" name="filter-sort-by">
     <option value=""><?php echo __( 'Sort by', 'realia' ); ?></option>
     <option value="price" <?php if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-sort-by'] ) && 'price' == $_GET['filter-sort-by'] ) :   ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo __( 'Price', 'realia' ); ?></option>
     <option value="title" <?php if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-sort-by'] ) && 'title' == $_GET['filter-sort-by'] ) :   ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo __( 'Title', 'realia' ); ?></option>

Comment: <option value="published" <?php if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-sort-by'] ) && 'published' == $_GET['filter-sort-by'] ) :   ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo __( 'Published', 'realia' ); ?></option>
    </select>
   </div><!-- /.filter-sort-by-wrapper -->

   <div class="properties-filter-sort-order-wrapper">
    <select class="form-control" name="filter-sort-order">
     <option value=""><?php echo __( 'Order', 'realia' ); ?></option>

Comment: <option value="asc" <?php if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-sort-order'] ) && 'asc' == $_GET['filter-sort-order'] ) :   ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo __( 'ASC', 'realia' ); ?></option>
     <option value="desc" <?php if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-sort-order'] ) && 'desc' == $_GET['filter-sort-order'] ) :   ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo __( 'DESC', 'realia' ); ?></option>
    </select>
   </div><!-- /.filter-sort-order-wrapper-->
  </div><!-- /.properties-sort-inner -->
 </form>
</div><!-- /.properties-sort -->

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to be random? The entries in the list? I'll add some possibilites to my answer above.

Comment: OK. I found your theme, it's this one, right: `http://preview.themeforest.net/item/realia-responsive-real-estate-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/4789838 and you want the different houses/properties displayed in a random order, right? They are already random though? I don't get what you want. I don't think I can help you. Your question is just to broad, and it seems you don't have any understanding of programming.